# Entity framework no key defined:key annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I used a Users entities class :

```
 public class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public int DayInvitation { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string EyesColors { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public int Popularity { get; set; }
}
```

I got the following error :

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Users' has no key defined.

So I added [Key] keyword..

```
 public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // ... 
}
```

Now my question is that, I'm pretty sure that I did another ASP .NET PROJECT (My first one, this the second one) without using this [Key] annotation, just by specifying the ProductId, can someone explain me why ? I can't understand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic primary key name discovery conventions are the following:

- you have a property named `Id`
- or you have a property named `YourClassNameId`.

In your case your class is named `Users` with an "s" at the end.

So in order to the convention work you need to name your property `UsersId` (note the "s") :

```
public class Users
{
    public int UsersId { get; set; } 
    //...
}
```

or just `Id`

```
public class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    //...
}
```

If you want to learn more about the convetions you can start with this great article:

[Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962)

which can be found at the [Entity Framework Learning center.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much, have you got some nice books name, or website where I can learn a lot of about EF? !!!

Comment: @SamMayback added some links if you are looking for books: http://learnentityframework.com/learnentityframework/